# Sharing network responsible for Windows Media Player "Server Execution Failed "in windows 7

Tags: network-shares, windows-media-player, data-execution-prevention

While playing LAN games i did kind of a messed up up with the sharing options for network.
After that i noticed LAN is perfect, but Windows Media Player is not playing any files. It is showing SERVER EXECUTION FAILED..

Is there any option to RESET the changes.
http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/3642/76574384.png

Answer (score 0):

If you run the [Fix-it for WMP](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_media_player_diagnostic/), does that help?